# bootstrap modal page on load issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have an "awesome" bootstrap modal bug. When document ready, the bootrap modal window rendered (not showing), and I can not click any links in this area. After I launched the modal, the issue has been eliminated.

here an screenshot:
http://d.pr/i/LK4f

tip, idea?

cheers,
daniel

Comment: add class "hide" to your modal

Answer (score 0):

Quick tip: try to remove the style="top:10%!important"

Answer (score 0):

I know this is long overdue, but I had the same "awesome bootstrap modal bug".

Adding `display: none;` to the `.modal {}` class sorted this one out for me.